# How to line up the ls -l list of files and directories in a column instead of printing horizontally?

Tags: awk, sed, ls

I'm trying to print the names of each file and directory for the current user, but it keeps printing in one big long line. I want to have each file present as a column, just as it does when I print ls -l.

You don't have to help with this, but for better context, I'm trying to make sure a colon ':' shows up after each file name, along with its group permissions from the first field. For example, it could look like "file/dir:---" or "file/dir:r--"

```
echo $(ls -l /home/$(whoami) | awk '{if (NR>1) print $9}'): $(ls -l /home/$(whoami) | awk '{if (NR>1) print $1}')
```

Comment: are you on a Linux system that has the `stat` command? Also, try the `ls -1` (number one) option.

Comment: Jeff, I am not sure. I use Terminal on Mac.

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: The actual answer to your question is that you did not quote the command substitution, so word splitting happens which converts newlines to spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls -1
```

will list one file per line. This is the default when `ls`’s output is redirected anywhere that’s not a terminal.

To get the output you’re after, you’d be better off doing something like

```
ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 { print $9 ":" $1 }'
```

or better still,

```
stat -c "%n:%A" *
```

although both of these list all the permissions, not just the group permissions. To only see group permissions, use

```
ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 { print $9 ":" substr($1,5,3) }'
```

or

```
stat -c "%n:%A" * | sed 's/....\(...\)...$/\1/'
```

(hat-tip to [user1404316](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153769/user1404316) for [the `sed` expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424173/86440)).

The `ls`-parsing variants don’t cope with spaces and other blank characters in file names, so they [shouldn’t be used in general](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440).

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler solution if you have access to a version of `find` that includes the GNU extensions. In order to find out, run `man find` and search for the `-printf` (To do that first press `/^ *-printf`). If you do, you are in luck, because your solution could be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f: %M\n" | sed 's/....\(...\)...$/\1/'
```

As a bonus, this answer will work in the unusual case of a file name
including the colon character.

Comment: Or with GNU 
stat: `stat -c '%n:%A' * | sed ...`

Comment: @glennjackman - nicer than mine!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the files for only the current user.

```
ls -l | awk -v var="$(whoami)" '$4 == var {print $9}'
```

That will only print files that belong to the current user, in the format you require.